# How do I include Images in my Database in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, database, image, visual-studio-2010

I'm fairly new to C# .Net.  We're being taught it at University and are using Visual Studio to create windows forms.  As a new part to the subject we're using databases, tables and datasets.

I opened a new Windows Form project and immediately added a new database to it.  The table I want to create will have 2 columns - ImageID and the image itself.  In what way do i add the image in to the box?  I've tried full path, relative path and dragging the image in, but whatever I do i get the same error message....

> *Invalid Value
>
>   The changed value in this cell was not recognized as being valid.
>   .Net Framework Data Type: Byte[]
>
>   Error Message: You cannot use the result pane to set this Field data to 
>   values other than NULL
>
>   Type a value appropriate for the data type or press ESC to cancel the
>   change*

How can I have images in there?  I just don't know how to use the image data type within the table.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so], you can easily google a tutorial https://www.google.com.au/search?q=store+images+in+SQL+server+winforms

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I've seen lots of tutorials, but they are all far more complex than what I have been taught and really are out of my realm of understanding at the moment.

Using the in-built functionality of visual studio I can create a dataset using my table and VS will basically create all my labels, textboxes and code to retrieve the data from my table.  That's what i'm trying to do, but with images in my table.  I don't need to store images in it from the program; i just want to display from my table in to a picture box.

VS won't accept anything in the table as data type image.

Comment: winforms... datasets... Good to see the course is keeping up... (Cough)

Comment: well i'm a networking student, not a programmer.  sorry.  c# is an additional course.

So i'm guessing either... that it's not possible to have images in my table or nobody knows the answer to my question.

Is the image datatype in the table just used as a placeholder and i need further code to put images in it?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is to store the image in the file system and only its path in the database. Basically you define a base folder:

```
string baseFolder = "c:\Program Files\MyApp\Images";
```

And use it to store relative paths in the database:

```
INSERT INTO ImagesTable (Name, Path)
Values ('German Shepherd', 'Dogs\german-shepherd.jpg')
```

Then, when you need to retrieve the image, you can do it like this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(baseFolder, 'Dogs\german-shepherd.jpg');
Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
```

In the following SO question you can find more information about the pros and cons of this approach:

- [Should I store my images in the database or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713243/should-i-store-my-images-in-the-database-or-folders)

Answer (score -1):

you can store images in sql server 2008. Just create database table having column datatype "image".
now from .net code use the file upload control to select the image file and then convert the image parameter into byte[] before inserting image data into the database.

Comment: [The `image` data-type is deprected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16); `varbinary` should be used instead. However, in many (if not most) cases it is inadvisable to store binary data sized greater than a few kilobytes in a table because the RDBMS will need to store those blobs separately from other data in the row which can significantly hamper performance.